# Generic classes and Class<T>

Tags: java, generics

Imagine we have a factory that creates object by its class. Question is - how to declare such factory for generic classes? For example, generic factory that can create Map<K,V> or List<T> or any other type. Of course, <K, V> Map<K, V> create() is not an answer.

If it is not possible, i'd like to know why from language design perspective.

EDIT: As mentioned by Marko, this question is really about compile-time type safety. How can i declare such factory to avoid warnings and manual casts?

Example:

```
import java.util.Map;

class Factory {
    public static <T> T create(Class<T> clazz) {
        return null;//some implementation here
    }
}

class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //works perfectly
        String s = Factory.create(String.class);

        //Type safety: The expression of type Map needs unchecked conversion to conform to Map<String,Integer>
        Map<String, Integer> map = Factory.create(Map.class);
        //How can we specify that T is Map<String, Integer> ?
        //Factory.<Map<String, Integer>>create(Map.class); - does not work
    }
}
```

Comment: I see people are still hung up on type erasure, but this question has nothing to do with it because it asks about *compile-time* type safety.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Type erasure is the reason why there's no `Map<String, Integer>.class` literal, and why only raw types can be created via reflection, both of which lead to the unchecked conversion to a generic type in cases like this.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle Type erasure is only indirectly involved because, if Java allowed `Map<String, Integer>.class`, that would be enough for the *compiler* to infer the type. You don't need an actual instance of a `Class` object to have the compiler know which type you are referring to; you just need an *expression* of the appropriate static type.

Comment: Are you just interested in declaring a `create` method that the client can use without seeing any warnings, or are you interested in actually doing this in a type safe way? If it's the first, you can use the signature `static <T> T create(TypeReference<T> type)` as in @MarkoTopolnik's answer. If it's the second, then it's impossible due to type erasure. Even if in your `create()` method you managed to use the argument `type` to get the `java.lang.reflect.Type` object representing `Map<String, Integer>`, you would still have to cast the object instantiated to a `T` and ignore a warning.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Just note that type erasure only gets in the way of type-*unsafe* operations, those which would in any case be liable to failing a runtime type check. Basically, erasure precludes `instanceof` evaluation and checked downcasts.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik That's true, but then before Java 5 it was always possible to use a raw `List` to store and retrieve only `String`s in a type safe way as long as you knew what you were doing - it's just that the compiler couldn't help you. When I say that you can't do this in a type safe way, I need to correct. What I really mean is that it is impossible in this case to use generics to get the compiler to verify that your code is type safe.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You make a good point about the class literal.  The current syntax was doubtless *inspired by* erasure, but you're absolutely right that the expression for the Class literal could carry the generic parameters, and thus type-check fully.  Thanks for making that explicit, I hadn't considered it before.

Comment: @pbabcdefp  Yes, the compiler can't ensure type safety here, but again, not due to erasure; rather due to the overall lack of power in Java's type system. Erasure means that the runtime won't be able to ensure type safety, either.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Further, in Java you surely *can* have `Class<HashMap<String,Integer>>`---as a static type. You just don't get class *literals* of that type. This is a legal method definition in Java, compiled without any type unsafety warnings: `static Map<String,Integer> newMap(Class<? extends Map<String,Integer>> klass) throws Exception { return klass.newInstance(); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class literal expression only represents the raw type. You cannot post-hoc parameterize its referent because it is a constant whose type is already fixed. Therefore there is no way for you to transfer the type parameter information you would need to have the compiler infer the fully parameterized generic type.

A workaround which works for APIs such as Jackson is to have a `TypeReference` and capture all the type parameters by creating an actual subclass with the params specified, such as

```
new TypeReference<Map<String,Integer>>() {}
```

When you pass this to a `create` method, the compiler will be able to infer its generic type parameter. Reflection will even allow you to retrieve the parametrization at runtime—type erasure isn't as pervasive as often presented.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible - and the reason why, is that generics were implemented via erasure, rather than being reified.  The short version of this is that "generics don't exist at runtime"; they are essentially just used for type-checking during compilation.  So there's no such thing as `Map<String, Integer>.class` or `Map<Long, List<String>>.class` - there's just the object `Map.class`.

But on the plus side, an object can also only *really* be of class `Map`, because of erasure.  So if you construct an object of the raw type `Map.class` via reflection, and cast it to a `Map<String, Integer>`, then it **is** a `Map<String, Integer>` with all the same properties as if it had been created in the normal way.

The warning is correct, in that it's saying you're asserting generic bounds that cannot be automatically checked by the compiler.  This is unavoidable for the reasons above, and is not a problem in this case.  I would add a comment here, suppress the warning and continue.  I'm not aware of a better/cleaner way to achieve what you're doing here.